# Load session from either of the table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Im trying to use a single sign on place for both admin table and member table.

This is in my button click on the code behind my asp master page:

```
  if (MemberDB.searchUsername(User.Text) != null) 
  {
    Member m = MemberDB.Login(User.Text, Password.Text);
    Session["ULogin"] = m;
    loginForm2.Visible = true;
    loginForm.Visible = false;
    LoginLabel.Text = "You are logged in as " + m.Name;
    } 
  else if (AdminDB.searchUsername(User.Text) != null)
  {
      Admin a = AdminDB.Login(User.Text, Password.Text);
      Session["ULogin"] = a;
      loginForm2.Visible = true;
      loginForm.Visible = false;
      LoginLabel.Text = "You are logged in as " + m.Name;
  }
    else
    {
                  ErrorLabel.Text = "Error in Login! Click <a href=\"ResetPassword.aspx\">here</a> to reset your password" ;
    }
```

What should i put in the page load of my master page to check if the user is admin or member?

Comment: Just a suggestion, why re work the wheel? Use a real membership framework, you can then assign roles to users. Plus I bet its a lot more secure that what you are writing, judging from the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design is wrong altogether. An admin *is* a user, just one who can do more. You should store administrative users in the same table as non-administrative ones.

With this design you need another field, like `Session["IsAdmin"]`, or check the type of `Session["ULogin"]`:

```
if (Session["ULogin"] is Admin)
{
    // ...
}
```